# WSSecurity error in .NET WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ws-security

In SOAP message sent from Java to .NET we have in header following section:

```
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-[SOMETHING]">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-[SOMETHING]">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
               <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=MY,OU=SOMETHING,O=XXX</ds:X509IssuerName>
               <ds:X509SerialNumber>1111111</ds:X509SerialNumber>
             </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
         </ds:X509Data>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
```

The error which we get:

```
Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier(
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = X509IssuerSerialKeyIdentifierClause(Issuer = 'CN=MY,OU=SOMETHING,O=XXX', Serial = '1111111'))', 
    available tokens 'SecurityTokenResolver(TokenCount = 0,)
```

.NET WCF service cannot by default using this header to validate message. The only accepted way is to include full certificate into message (instead of path to store), like following:

```
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-11035BFBDD92F5CE7C1399467228150959">
   <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>[BASE 64 of certyficate]</ds:X509Certificate>
   </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

The similar problem and above solution was described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhrubach/archive/2010/06/18/10027513.aspx

But in my case I cannot change service in Java. I see following solutions:

1. Create "proxy" in Java which will validate above message and send to .NET WCF message without WSSecurity - I will prefer not to do this, because this add one more component to my solution in other technology
2. "Intercept" incoming message to replace content of X509Data based on store certyficate. I tried to [MessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) with ServiceBehavior, but they are called after WSSecurity validation - so too late.

So my question is can I somehow intercept message before WSSecurity validation or there is an other way to achieve validation of this kind of message in .NET?

Comment: Ouch, I understand the issue, but I'm sure I cannot answer, I can only +1. Unfortunately it is of course safer to only use things like `MessageInspector` after verification, so you'll probably need to hook into the security component itself. Alternatively you could create a proxy that parses and replaces the XML based on element & namespace.